# Let $R$ be the region enclosed by the curves $x = y^2 + 1, x = 5, y = −3$ and $y = 3$

Tags: calculus, area, solid-of-revolution

(i) Sketch the region $R$.
(ii) Find the area of region $R$.

Can someone tell me if i am doing it correctly since [image]i tried it out and sketch a graph like the one on the picture but the points $y=3$ and $y=-3$ makes me confuse since i did my sketch but never use those two points also the question never mentioned if the function revolve about either $x$-axis or $y$-axis.

Comment: It is certainly convusing since $x = y^2 + 1, x = 5$ encloses a region (shaded above), but $y=3$ does not intersect the region.  $x = y^2 + 1, x = 5, y = 3$ encloses a roughly triangular region.  But $y = -3$ does not intersect the region.  My best answer would be to say the question is somewhat ambiguous as there are 3 separate regions enclosed by these curves.  Identify all three.  I would then find the area of each and say what the area is all together.

Comment: $x=5$ gives $y=2$ or $y=-2$ not 3.

Comment: so is my sketch correct or not.

Comment: @DougM  can  elaborate more on that. the three regions and confirm if the sketch is somewhat correct or not??

Comment: @Surdz https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2yuvhhpngs ... I am confused too

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima okay when y=3, x=(3)^2+1=10 and when x=-3, y=(-3)^2+1=10 thats what you mean then there is three regions, yes or??

Comment: Thnk Donald for the helpful graph.+1

Answer (score 2):

This would be my sketch:

[image]

And I would calculate the area to be:

$\displaystyle {\int_{-3}^{-2} (y^2 +1) - 5 \ dy + \int_{-2}^{2} 5-(y^2 +1)\ dy + \int_{2}^{3} (y^2 +1)-5\ dy}$

Comment: You have a typo on the upper limit of the middle integral.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales thanks!

Comment: @DougM i dont understand how you got your limits of integration. since i think region 1 (green color) limit is from 3-10, region 2(red color) is from 1-5 and lastly blue region is from -3 to 10. really need explanation here.

Comment: I am integrating with respect to $y.$  I think it is easier that way.  If you wanted to integrate with respect to $x. \cdots 2\int_1^5 \sqrt {x^2+1}\ dx + 2\int_5^{10} 3-\sqrt {x^2+1}\ dx$

Answer (score 0):

There are two curves
$$y=\sqrt {x-1} $$ and $$y=-\sqrt {x-1} $$
$$y=\pm 3\implies x=10$$
By symetry, the area between them is
$$2\int_5^{10}\sqrt {x-1}dx=$$
$$=2 \Bigl[\frac {2}{3}(x-1)^\frac 32\Bigr]_5^{10} $$
$$\frac {4}{3}(27-8)=\frac {76}{3} $$

Using Donald's graph, the area you look for is

$$(10-5)(3+3)-\frac {76}{3}=\frac {14}{3} $$